# I am trying to write an ARM 64 Assembly program to implement a SELECT/CASE construct

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

I am creating an `ARM` Assembly Language framework to implement a `SELECT/CASE` construct.

The format is:

```
SELECT number
    CASE 1:
        << statements if number is 1 >>
    CASE 2:
        << statements if number is 2 >>
    CASE ELSE:
        << statement if not any other case >>
```

This is what I have tried but the program does not output the messages based on the entered number:

```
// Declare program entry point
.global _start

// Messages to be displayed
.data
prompt:     .asciz "Input a number: "  // Prompt message
case1_msg:  .asciz "You entered 1\n"  // Case 1 message
case2_msg:  .asciz "You entered 2\n"  // Case 2 message
else_msg:   .asciz "You entered a value other than 1 and 2\n"  // Else message

.text
_start:
    // Display prompt and get user input
    mov     x0, #0          // Set output to stdout
    adr     x1, prompt      // Load prompt address
    mov     x2, #17         // Set prompt length
    mov     x8, #64         // Call Linux write function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call
    mov     x0, #0          // Set input to stdin
    mov     x8, #63         // Call Linux read function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call

    // Check user input against cases
    cmp     w0, #1          // Compare input with case 1
    beq     case1           // Branch to case 1 if equal
    cmp     w0, #2          // Compare input with case 2
    beq     case2           // Branch to case 2 if equal
    b       else_case      // Branch to else case if not equal to either case

case1:
    // Perform actions for case 1
    adr     x0, case1_msg   // Load case 1 message address
    mov     x8, #64         // Call Linux write function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call
    b       end_select     // Branch to end of case1

case2:
    // Perform actions for case 2
    adr     x0, case2_msg   // Load case 2 message address
    mov     x8, #64         // Call Linux write function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call
    b       end_select     // Branch to end of case2

else_case:
    // Perform actions for else case
    adr     x0, else_msg    // Load else message address
    mov     x8, #64         // Call Linux write function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call

end_select:
    // Terminate program
    mov     x0, #0          // Set return code to 0
    mov     x8, #93         // Call Linux exit function
    svc     #0              // Execute system call
```

Comment: Are you expecting the Linux `read` syscall to return you an integer in `w0`?  Why do you expect that?  Do you know what parameters the `read` syscall expects?

Comment: You're checking the return value of `read` to see if 1, 2, or another amount of bytes was read.  Since you didn't set `x1` and `x2` after the previous `write`, you're probably overwriting the `prompt:` string with the actual input data, since you put it in writeable memory for some reason.  If it had been in `.rodata`, you'd have gotten a `-EFAULT` return value.  Use `gdb` to single-step your code and look at registers, and `strace ./a.out` to trace the actual system-call args and return values.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm new in this language I'm just trying to learn

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright thanks . Let me see.

Comment: The `read` system call is documented in the man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), which describes its return value vs. what it stores in a buffer.  So if you know some C, and the calling convention (e.g. that `x0` is always the return value), you're all set.  All system calls follow the same calling convention, and the Linux man page will mention differences between the glibc wrapper and the raw kernel interface like you get with `svc`, if there are any.  (e.g. for `nice(2)` or `clone(2)`)

Comment: Have you tried writing the exact same program in C, using the exact same syscalls, and looking at the resulting assembly?

Comment: Still can't make it work. I will appreciate if anyone can help me make the program work correctly @PeterCordes

Comment: You should be doing an `lb` from the first byte of the buffer, and comparing against `'1'` or `'2'` (ASCII codes).  IDK what you attempted, but use a debugger to single-step your code like I said.

Comment: You're trying to learn too many things in one program all together at the same time.  Get a simpler program with only the switch/case working without all those syscalls, test each case to make sure it works and the program runs properly to completion for each case.  Then get each of those syscalls working in their own simple program that runs properly to completion.  Then combine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The issue was that I was comparing an integer with a character. I converted the character into an integer and the compared and everything worked as expected. I appreciate everyone who contributed to help me figure out what was the problem.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
// Assembler program to implement a SELECT/CASE construct
.global _start // Provide program starting address
_start:
     //Display a message and prompt for input
     mov    X0, #0
     ldr    X1, =prompt // Load address of prompt message
     mov    X2, #74 // length of the prompt message
     mov    X8, #64 // call Linux
     svc    0  //display the message

     //Reading the user input
     mov    X0, #0
     ldr    X1, =input  // Load address of input buffer
     mov    X2, #10     // input size
     mov    X8, #63     // system call
     svc    0           // read input from keyboard

     // From ASCII to integer conversion
     ldrb   W0, [X1]    // load the character
     sub    W0, W0, #'0'// convert to integer
     cmp    W0, #1      // check if the value is 1
     b.eq   print_one   // if true print message for 1
     cmp    W0, #2      // check if it is 2
     b.eq   print_two   // print message for two

    // This will execute if the input is not 1 or 2
     ldr    X1, =unknown// "unknown" message string
     mov    X2, #49 // length of the string
     mov    X0, #1 // 1 = StdOut
     mov    X8, #64 // write system call
     svc    0 // system call to print
     b      exit // move to exit

//this option will be executed if the user enters 1
print_one:
     //print "one" message
     ldr    X1, =one // message string
     mov    X2, #29 // length of the string
     mov    X8, #64 // write system call
     svc    0  // call to output message
     b      exit  // move to exit

print_two:
     // Print "two" message
     ldr    X1, =two // message string
     mov    X2, #29 // lenth of the string
     mov    X8, #64 // write system call
     svc    0  // call to output message
     b      exit  // move to exit

exit:
     // Exiting program
     mov    X0, #0 // Use 0 return code
     mov    X8, #93 // Service code 93 terminates
     svc    0 // Call Linux to terminate

.data
//different messages to be displayed
prompt:  .ascii "Implement a Select/Case structure:\n1. Case 1 actions\n2. Case 2 actions\n"
input:   .skip 10      // Input buffer for read system call
one:     .ascii "case 1 actions will be taken\n"
two:     .ascii "case 2 actions will be taken\n"
unknown: .ascii "input does not match with any case. Else actions\n"
//end of the program
```